# What adjective can describe someone who counts his chickens before they're hatched?

Tags: adjectives, pejorative-language

For example, someone who writes "I chose to study biology and chemistry at school because I am going to become a doctor after graduating."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps *[presumptuous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/presumptuous)*

> characterized by presumption or tending to presume; bold; forward

*[Presume](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/presume?showCookiePolicy=true)* is defined as

> to take (something) for granted; assume

You also may consider

> - pushy
> - forward
> - bold
> - arrogant
> - rash
> - audacious
> - conceited
> - foolhardy
> - overconfident
> - bigheaded

Comment: Thanks, I thought of presumptuous too, but the OED defines it as "failing to observe the limits of what is permitted or appropriate" which is not quite what I had in mind. Your other suggestion, "overconfident", sounds closer to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***overconfident*** given that the dictionary definition of the idiom implies being extremely (or hastily) hopeful about a future occurrence.

[***overconfidence***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overconfidence)
(noun)

excessive confidence, boldness or sureness of yourself
excessive confidence, sureness or trust (in something)

(adjective) *overconfident*

excessively confident